# Postgres SSL issue preventing connection

Tags: postgresql, ssl

I have updated to Postgres 14 and am attempting to set up the config file to use the same SSL keys that the server was using before when running 13.

SSL connections work fine and the server behaves correctly when the SSL keys are left at the default 'snakeoil' keys (I'm on an Ubuntu 20 AWS Ec2). As soon as I change to self generated keys, which have been working previously, psql, pgadmin and sqlalchemy cannot connect (I wanted to try various different perumtations) even where ssl is not required. I have ensured that the keys are in the quoted data directory from the config file, and have tried both just quoting the name of the keys as well as the complete addresses.

The postgresql service is running. Previously I was getting an error specfically quoting that the keys cannot be found, but I can't remember or find what command I issued to produce that behaviour. But this lends me to believe that either my keys cannot be found (they are currently protected under 0444) or that I am not specifying the locations correctly.

Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

I can continue with snakeoil for now but would rather switch to my own keys that I can eventually get signed by a CA for production.

EDIT with logs:

Attempting to connect via psql:

---

psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?

---

Logs, entries generated whilst database is running using snakeoil keys, stops when a restart is requested when the config file changes:

---

2021-11-23 15:23:50.190 UTC,,,7604,,619d0786.1db4,1,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"ending log output to stderr",,"Future log output will go to log destination ""csvlog"".",,,,,,,"","postmaster",,0
2021-11-23 15:23:50.190 UTC,,,7604,,619d0786.1db4,2,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"starting PostgreSQL 14.1 (Ubuntu 14.1-2.pgdg20.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, 64-bit",,,,,,,,,"","postmaster",,0
2021-11-23 15:23:50.190 UTC,,,7604,,619d0786.1db4,3,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"listening on IPv4 address ""0.0.0.0"", port 5432",,,,,,,,,"","postmaster",,0
2021-11-23 15:23:50.190 UTC,,,7604,,619d0786.1db4,4,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"listening on IPv6 address ""::"", port 5432",,,,,,,,,"","postmaster",,0
2021-11-23 15:23:50.192 UTC,,,7604,,619d0786.1db4,5,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"listening on Unix socket ""/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432""",,,,,,,,,"","postmaster",,0
2021-11-23 15:23:50.199 UTC,,,7606,,619d0786.1db6,1,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"database system was shut down at 2021-11-23 15:08:40 UTC",,,,,,,,,"","startup",,0
2021-11-23 15:23:50.206 UTC,,,7604,,619d0786.1db4,6,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"database system is ready to accept connections",,,,,,,,,"","postmaster",,0
2021-11-23 15:23:50.209 UTC,,,7612,,619d0786.1dbc,1,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,2/0,0,LOG,00000,"TimescaleDB background worker launcher connected to shared catalogs",,,,,,,,,"","TimescaleDB Background Worker Launcher",,0
2021-11-23 15:26:24.769 UTC,"postgres","postgres",7720,"[local]",619d0816.1e28,1,"idle",2021-11-23 15:26:14 UTC,7/147,0,ERROR,42601,"syntax error at or near ""l""",,,,,,"l;",1,,"psql","client backend",,0
2021-11-23 15:26:26.868 UTC,"postgres","postgres",7720,"[local]",619d0816.1e28,2,"idle",2021-11-23 15:26:14 UTC,7/148,0,ERROR,42601,"syntax error at or near ""ls""",,,,,,"ls;",1,,"psql","client backend",,0
2021-11-23 15:28:43.657 UTC,,,7604,,619d0786.1db4,7,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"received fast shutdown request",,,,,,,,,"","postmaster",,0
2021-11-23 15:28:43.660 UTC,,,7604,,619d0786.1db4,8,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"aborting any active transactions",,,,,,,,,"","postmaster",,0
2021-11-23 15:28:43.660 UTC,,,7616,,619d0786.1dc0,1,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,4/0,0,LOG,57P01,"terminating TimescaleDB job scheduler due to administrator command",,,,,,,,,"","TimescaleDB Background Worker Scheduler",,0
2021-11-23 15:28:43.660 UTC,,,7616,,619d0786.1dc0,2,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,4/0,0,FATAL,57P01,"terminating background worker ""TimescaleDB Background Worker Scheduler"" due to administrator command",,,,,,,,,"","TimescaleDB Background Worker Scheduler",,0
2021-11-23 15:28:43.662 UTC,,,7615,,619d0786.1dbf,1,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,6/0,0,LOG,57P01,"terminating TimescaleDB job scheduler due to administrator command",,,,,,,,,"","TimescaleDB Background Worker Scheduler",,0
2021-11-23 15:28:43.662 UTC,,,7615,,619d0786.1dbf,2,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,6/0,0,FATAL,57P01,"terminating background worker ""TimescaleDB Background Worker Scheduler"" due to administrator command",,,,,,,,,"","TimescaleDB Background Worker Scheduler",,0
2021-11-23 15:28:43.663 UTC,,,7614,,619d0786.1dbe,1,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,5/0,0,LOG,57P01,"terminating TimescaleDB job scheduler due to administrator command",,,,,,,,,"","TimescaleDB Background Worker Scheduler",,0
2021-11-23 15:28:43.663 UTC,,,7614,,619d0786.1dbe,2,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,5/0,0,FATAL,57P01,"terminating background worker ""TimescaleDB Background Worker Scheduler"" due to administrator command",,,,,,,,,"","TimescaleDB Background Worker Scheduler",,0
2021-11-23 15:28:43.667 UTC,,,7612,,619d0786.1dbc,2,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,2/0,0,FATAL,57P01,"terminating background worker ""TimescaleDB Background Worker Launcher"" due to administrator command",,,,,,,,,"","TimescaleDB Background Worker Launcher",,0
2021-11-23 15:28:43.670 UTC,,,7604,,619d0786.1db4,9,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"background worker ""TimescaleDB Background Worker Launcher"" (PID 7612) exited with exit code 1",,,,,,,,,"","postmaster",,0
2021-11-23 15:28:43.670 UTC,,,7604,,619d0786.1db4,10,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"background worker ""logical replication launcher"" (PID 7613) exited with exit code 1",,,,,,,,,"","postmaster",,0
2021-11-23 15:28:43.670 UTC,,,7604,,619d0786.1db4,11,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"background worker ""TimescaleDB Background Worker Scheduler"" (PID 7615) exited with exit code 1",,,,,,,,,"","postmaster",,0
2021-11-23 15:28:43.670 UTC,,,7604,,619d0786.1db4,12,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"background worker ""TimescaleDB Background Worker Scheduler"" (PID 7616) exited with exit code 1",,,,,,,,,"","postmaster",,0
2021-11-23 15:28:43.670 UTC,,,7614,,619d0786.1dbe,3,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,,0,LOG,57P01,"terminating TimescaleDB job scheduler due to administrator command",,,,,,,,,"","TimescaleDB Background Worker Scheduler",,0
2021-11-23 15:28:43.671 UTC,,,7604,,619d0786.1db4,13,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"background worker ""TimescaleDB Background Worker Scheduler"" (PID 7614) exited with exit code 1",,,,,,,,,"","postmaster",,0
2021-11-23 15:28:43.671 UTC,,,7607,,619d0786.1db7,1,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"shutting down",,,,,,,,,"","checkpointer",,0
2021-11-23 15:28:43.692 UTC,,,7604,,619d0786.1db4,14,,2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"database system is shut down",,,,,,,,,"","postmaster",,0

---

So the server fails to restart after the requested restart (there is no later log file).

and yet:

---

:/var/lib/postgresql/14$ systemctl status postgresql
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (exited) since Tue 2021-11-23 15:28:43 UTC; 7min ago
Process: 7814 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 7814 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 23 15:28:43 ip-172-31-17-218 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Nov 23 15:28:43 ip-172-31-17-218 systemd[1]: Finished PostgreSQL RDBMS.

---

So it's failing to restart due to the key change, and yet the systemctl is claiming it's running.

I still think I've made a mistake somewhere but cannot figure out where.

I'm using .crt and .key files, as they functioned fine with postgres-13, does postgres-14 require .pem?

Comment: Add verbatim copies of the error message and the PostgreSQL log entries to the question.

Comment: `postgresql.service` is a stub service that launches the actual Postgres instance or instances an then exits per `(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)`. To see what is running do `ps ax | grep postgres`

Comment: I'm not seeing anything referring to SSL keys in the log.  I do see `2021-11-23 15:23:50 UTC,,0,LOG,00000,"received fast shutdown request",,,,,,,,,"","postmaster"`. Is there anything in system logs that can shed light on what sent the shutdown request?

Comment: I asked for a postgres service restart to reload the config file after changing it from snakeoil to my own keys. I assumed that the fast shutdown request was due to the restart and then something due to the new keys has prevented the restart from completing.

Comment: Issue solved, it was a permissions issue after all, which was preventing postgres from reading the key files which caused pg_ctl to crash on start up. This was not logged in the postgres logs but was in the system logs. Thanks for everyones help :)